# Nvidia GPU simultaneous access to a single location in global memory

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I was wondering what happens when multiple threads within a single warp try to access the same location in global memory (e.g., the same 4 byte word), particularly in Turing GPUs with compute capability 7.5. I believe that in shared memory that would result in a bank conflict, unless all of the threads access the same location, then the data would be broadcasted.

Just to give a contrived example:

1) Consider that the first 16 threads of a warp access a single 4-byte word, whereas the remaining 16 threads access the next single 4-byte word. How the access is handled in such situation? Is it serialized for every thread of a half warp?

2) What if the entire warp tries to access a single 4-byte word from a global memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no serialization.  All CUDA GPUs Kepler and newer will broadcast in that scenario.  There is no performance hit.
2. No difference.  Any pattern of overlapping read access is handled in a single request, with an optimized number of transactions per request. The transactions per request would be no higher than for an ordinary coalesced one-thread-per-adjacent-location type read, and may be lower.  For example, on a modern GPU, you might observe 4 (32-byte) transactions per coalesced global read request.  In the case of all threads (in a warp) accessing a single location, it would be only one transaction per request.